# First admin account - laravel oauth

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

To identify people in my web app i use google Oauth server- only by this method users can log in app. But i need to create user with admin privileges

```
if(!DB::table('users')->count()) { grant this dude admin privileges;}
```

in login controller ? every time when someone wanna make account this little if will be executed - if in itself is not so hard to execute but every time it also do db query, so any way to avoid that?

Comment: Use role based authentication model rather than using the query.

Comment: use role based authentication and eloquent instead of DB.